# how to use where and and order by together in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select  
  Orders.OrderID, 
  Orders.OrderDate,  
  Customers.CustomerID, 
  Customers.City,
  Customers.Country 
from 
  Orders, 
  Customers 
where 
  (Customers.City like '[abc]%') and 
order by Customers.Country desc;
```

It shows the following error :

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(Customers.City
>   like '[abc]%') and'

I am not so expert in sql.

so please help me .

Comment: Remove `and` before `order by`

Comment: Presumably the `AND` is an unfinished join condition.

Comment: You probably need some condition (ideally by introducing `JOIN`) which indicates how rows from `Orders` and `Customers` are meant to be related to each other.

Comment: When you get the grip of the valid SQL code formatting, it will get obvious...

Comment: You don't need a `()` around the `WHERE` condition. `Customers.City like '[abc]%'` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `and` before `order by`

```
select  Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate,  Customers.CustomerID, Customers.City,Customers.Country 
from Orders, Customers 
where (Customers.City like '[abc]%') 
/*and you should add a condition something like 
  Orders.CustomerID= Customers.CustomerID*/
order by Customers.Country desc;
```

Comment: The problem was that the and after where (Customers.City like '[abc]%')
indicates you're going to add an additional piece of logic to the where clause. So removing the And will solve the problem as Parado has done above.

Comment: or before order by :)

Answer (score 3):

---

Remove and from your query......

Answer (score 3):

Simple, remove the `AND`

```
SELECT ORDERS.ORDERID, 
       ORDERS.ORDERDATE, 
       CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERID, 
       CUSTOMERS.CITY, 
       CUSTOMERS.COUNTRY 
FROM   ORDERS, 
       CUSTOMERS 
WHERE  ( CUSTOMERS.CITY LIKE '[abc]%' ) 
ORDER  BY CUSTOMERS.COUNTRY DESC;
```

Good luck!

Comment: This still leaves a cross join.

Comment: @MartinSmith, is leaving a cross join a problem?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the answers simply removing the `AND` give the desired semantics. It finds the customers matching the city then multiplies that result set out by all the orders irrespective of whether they have any relationship to that customer or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select  Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate,  Customers.CustomerID,   
   Customers.City,Customers.Country 
       from Orders, Customers 
     where Customers.City like '[abc]%'
   order by Customers.Country desc;
```

No need `and` in between `where` and `order by`

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
select  Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderDate,  Customers.CustomerID, Customers.City,Customers.Country 
from Orders, Customers 
where (Customers.City like '[abc]%') 
order by Customers.Country desc;
```

I removed only `and` just before `order by`. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the and:

```
where (Customers.City like '[abc]%')
```